# How can I use transformation properties to obtain the distribution of $h(\mathbf{s})$?

Tags: distributions, data-transformation, uniform-distribution, derivative, analytical

Let that $\mathbf{s}=(s_1,s_2) \sim Unif(S)$, where $S$ is some spatial area. Suppose $y=h(\mathbf{s})=1-[exp(exp(\beta_0+\beta_1(\mathbf{s}-\mathbf{x})^T(\mathbf{s}-\mathbf{x})))]^{-1}$. We have that $\frac{\partial h}{\partial \mathbf{s}}=2\beta_1e^{\beta_0+\beta_1\cdot Tr[(\mathbf{s}-\mathbf{x})^T(\mathbf{s}-\mathbf{x})]}exp[-(\beta_0+\beta_1\cdot Tr[(\mathbf{s}-\mathbf{x})^T(\mathbf{s}-\mathbf{x})])](\mathbf{s}-\mathbf{x})$. How can I obtain the distribution for $h(\mathbf{s})$ analytically?

**My idea:**

I was thinking of using Theorem 2.1.5 in Casella and Berger:
$$f_y(y)=f_\mathbf{s}(h^{-1}(y))|\frac{d}{d\mathbf{s}}h^{-1}(y)|$$

However, I'm not sure if this theorem extends to the multivariate case that I have.

Comment: Given that $S$ is only some vague "spatial area," could you explain what it might mean to write the distribution of $h(s)$ "analytically"?

Comment: @whuber Thanks for asking for clarification. My main objective is to have the distribution of $y=h(\mathbf{s})$. I wrote that $S$ is some spatial area, but for simplicity, let's assume that $s_1 \sim U(0,1)$ and $s_2 \sim U(0,1)$.

Comment: The expression will be nasty even in that case, because level sets of $y$ are circles (concentric around $x$) while the boundaries are portions of lines.  That makes this an unappetizing question.  Sometimes the original statistical problem will suggest useful approximations.  Could you provide some background?

Comment: @whuber Yes, here is some more background. My objective is to obtain the PDF of the probability of seeing a bird given that I am at location $\mathbf{x}$ and the bird's nest (and thus center of flight) is at $\mathbf{s}$. Here, I use the deterministic equation involving the "sight probability" is $h(p)=log(-log(1-p))=\beta_0+\beta_1(\mathbf{s}-\mathbf{x})^T(\mathbf{s}-\mathbf{x})$.

Comment: How far is $x$ from $S$?  The problem of approximating $h$ becomes three separate ones depending on whether $x$ is far from $S$ (compared to its diameter), near $S$, or within $S.$

Comment: @whuber $x$ can be within $S$ or outside of it

Comment: You will need to evaluate the integral numerically.

Comment: @whuber is there a way to show that I cannot integrate it analytically?

Comment: Clearly the integral depends on the details of the boundary of $S:$ in that sense it's obviously messy except, perhaps, when the boundary is a circle centered at $x.$  It remains possible that an analytical solution exists for the unit square case, but I doubt anyone would want to work it out.  Your best bet would be to apply *Mathematica* to the problem to see if it can produce anything for a specific, extremely simple $x$ (such as the center of the square or one of its corners).  If it can't even make progress in that case, the problem is hopeless.

Comment: @whuber okay, thank you for your input. Do I just delete this post then?

Comment: You might find it more constructive to modify your question.  You might describe your problem in scientific terms, give a short summary of your data, and ask for suggestions about reasonable statistical models that could lead to tractable solutions, for instance.

Comment: @whuber my classmate and I actually found a working model for what we want to do, but I was curious to see if we could get this one (which was my first idea) to work. I suppose I am just stubborn to see if my idea would be fruitful!